# how to take snapshot of PV automatically when POD deletion trigger?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am working on a snapshotting of PV before POD deletion completes.
I have written a controller which works on delete event of POD, but by the time it triggers delete event POD deletion is already completed.

I want to do below things automatically between  POD termination signal and deleted.

- Take snapshot of PV
- Update PVC with Snapshot DataSource
- Delete PV

Any ideas on how to implement this flow ...

Answer (score 0):

Do you set a finalizer for this pod in your controller?
If you  set a finalizer, The pod deletion will be  blocked till you delete the finalizer in your controller ;
You can  snapshot you pv  when event POD deletion is triggered,  and  when finished, delete the finalizer, and  update its status.